# Phonegap json '\r\n' coming data from server

Tags: mysql, json, phonegap-desktop-app

I am developing an app using phonegap whereI am taking some data from MySql table using php code.. but when I display the reslting text .. there is '\n\r' in the text ... how to remove this and display the result... I am giving my javascript code below

```
var jsonData;
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://mybirthsecrets.com/app/get_pday1_number_phonegap.php', 
    data: {pone: dayb}, 
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (result) { 
    jsonData = result;
        alert(jsonData);

    }
});
```

Comment: There are `\r\n` and not `\n\r`, right?

Comment: @Spoom .. sorry it is likethat..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jocheved it is very easy ..

```
 jsonData = result;
```

Instead of this line give the following line

```
 jsonData=eval('(' + result + ')');
```

Comment: This is great if you want to open up your site to CSRF injections.

Comment: No, it isn't. If you evaluate stuff coming from *the database* then the user can just put `<script>alert('malicious');</script>` into the database, and the phone application would evaluate it. Since this is with phonegap, you might even risk someone being able to destroy the phone. It might work, but it's not the right way of doing it. You can also open a window with a hammer, but that doesn't mean it's the way to open it.

Comment: @Jocheved Yes, fix the data from the source rather than in the destination. You need to fix where it's being output in the PHP file. What you're doing is sending a package to your friend with a brick, a keychain and a note saying "please throw out the brick". Why bother sending the brick all together?

Comment: @Jocheved Wherever `\r\n` is stored or coming from. If it's stored in MySQL, store it as an actual newline. Don't have MySQL store `\r\n` as "a backslash followed by an R followed by a backslash followed by an N". It's probably because you use `addslashes` which is the incorrect way of escaping SQL. Use prepared statements and bind variables to avoid SQL injection.